# if echo statement

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

Please help.

Every time I add this to my page is displays as Server Error. What is wrong with this code

```
<? if ($product['mark_special_offer']==1?) echo "<img src="/gfx/products/overlays/new-product.gif" alt="NEW" class="new_product" />"; ?>
```

Any suggestions (I bet it is obvious and I have missed a ' )

Comment: You have to escape `"` inside `"`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't escape your `"`, but you can easily write:

```
'<img src="/gfx/products/overlays/new-product.gif" alt="NEW" class="new_product" />'
```

instead. Or escape:

```
"<img src=\"/gfx/products/overlays/new-product.gif\" alt=\"NEW\" class=\"new_product\" />"
```

Answer (score 0):

syntax errors:

```
<? if ($product['mark_special_offer']==1?) echo "<img src="/gfx/products/overlays/new-product.gif" alt="NEW" class="new_product" />"; ?>
                                        ^                 ^--and other quotes
```